# Python Tkinter widgets not showing when parent is self only root why?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am making a GUI and this is the same exact code from another project were the widgets show up when `self` is their parent. But for some reason in this script they only will show if `root` is set as parent why? The Image Label does not show but the frame does and vice versa if I switch the parents.

```
import tkinter as tk
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageTk
import sys, os

#GUI Class
class MainGUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent=parent
        
        self.test()

    def test(self):
        self.bImage = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL.Image.open("Background.png"))
        self.bLabel = tk.Label(self, image=self.bImage)
        self.bLabel.image=self.bImage
        self.bLabel.place(x=0,y=0,width=300,height=400)

        self.test = tk.Frame(root, bg="red")
        self.test.place(x=10,y=10,width=50,height=50)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=tk.Tk()
    root.title("Buddy Swap")
    root.geometry("300x400")
    root.resizable(0,0)
    root.iconbitmap(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])+"\\Icon.ico")
    MainGUI(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `place` for the label. `place` doesn't cause the containing widget to grow or shrink so the frame is staying its default size of 1x1 pixel.

Unless you are very careful with `place` these sorts of problems can happen quite easily, and this is one of the reasons I recommend either `grid` or `pack` over `place` in almost every circumstance.

A simple fix is to either give your `MainGUI` frame a size so that the widgets inside are visible, or stop using `place`.

Comment: Thank you. For my project place seemed to be the best solution. I set the MainGUI frame size for it to work.

Comment: @LostSilverCoin: if you ever run this code on a system with a different resolution or different default fonts, be aware that your layout may not look good or resize properly.

Comment: thank you for the heads up. I am still learning you have actually helped me out in the past when I first started years ago but took a break and forgot it all lol. thank you have a good day.